# MVVMCross Messenger Plugin Android

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

Reffering to N=9 what I would like to do is in place of ILocationService I have my own INavigationService and a Navigation Service class.

```
  public class NavigationService :INavigationService
{
    private readonly IMvxMessenger _navigator;

    public NavigationService(IMvxMessenger navigator)
    {
        _navigator = navigator;
    }

    public void OnNavigation(PurchasesDataEntryViewModel vm)
    {
        var navigationMessage = new NavigationMessage(this,vm);
        _navigator.Publish(navigationMessage);
    }

}
```

And this is my Messenger class:

```
   public class NavigationMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public string ShopID { private set; get; }
    public int TotalStock { private set; get; }
    public int TotalPurchases { private set; get; }
    public int Stock1 { private set; get; }
    public int Stock2 { private set; get; }
    public int Stock3 { private set; get; }
    public int Purch1 { private set; get; }
    public int Purch2 { private set; get; }
    public int Purch3 { private set; get; }
    public string Name { private set; get; }
    public string CPrice { private set; get; }
    public int CSales { private set; get; }
    public string BrandID { private set; get; }
    public string CatID { private set; get; }
    public int LadgePur { private set; get; }
    public decimal LPrice { private set; get; }
    public int LPurch { private set; get; }
    public int LSales { private set; get; }
    public int LStock { private set; get; }
    public int LStock1 { private set; get; }
    public string MeasureID { private set; get; }


    public NavigationMessage(object sender, PurchasesDataEntryViewModel vm)
        : base(sender)
    {
        ShopID = vm.ShopID;
        TotalStock = vm.TotalStock;
        TotalPurchases = vm.TotalPurchases;
        Stock1 = vm.Stock1;
        Stock2 = vm.Stock2;
        Stock3 = vm.Stock3;
        //Purch1 = vm.Purch1;
        //Purch2 = vm.Purch2;
        //Purch3 = vm.Purch3;
        Name = vm.Name;
        CPrice = vm.CPrice;
      //  CSales = vm.CSales;
        BrandID = vm.BrandID;
        CatID = vm.CatID;
        LadgePur = vm.LadgePur;
        LPrice = vm.LPrice;
        LPurch = vm.LPurch;
        LSales = vm.LSales;
        LStock = vm.LStock;
        LStock1 = vm.LStock1;
        MeasureID = vm.MeasureID;
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to send the above values to my subscriber PurchasesDataEntryViewModel

```
 private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

    public PurchasesDataEntryViewModel(IDataService dataService,INavigationService service, IMvxMessenger navigator)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _token = navigator.Subscribe<NavigationMessage>(OnNavigationMessage);
    }

    private void OnNavigationMessage(NavigationMessage navigationMessage)
    {
        ShopID = navigationMessage.ShopID;
        .
        .
        .

    }
```

}

I cannot make it to work. I need to understand the interaction and lifecycle of Publish/Subscribe. How do the two viewmodels will understand how to communicate. I need somehow to tell my Messenger service that I want to send parameters from ViewModel A to ViewModel B through the messenger class. This is the first time I use the plugin so forgive me for the stupid questions.

Comment: What does `i cannot make it to work` mean? An exception? A crash? Some trace? Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the `Messenger` class `Publish` and `Subscribe` methods is introduced in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#Messenger

Your use of the calls in the code in the question looks good to me - any message published by your navigation service should be received by all existing `PurchasesDataEntryViewModel`s

---

**Update** After your comment about:

> when I publish the message I'am expecting my debugger to fire the constructor of the PurchasesDataEntryViewModel class

This is incorrect.

Any messenger (MvvmCross or not) can only pass messages between existing objects - it can't create new listeners dynamically.

If you do want a new object created in response to a message, then you will need to subscribe to that message type from a `Factory` object - and that `Factory` object will then need to create the new objects in its message handler.

```
private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

public Factory(IMvxMessenger navigator)
{
    _token = navigator.Subscribe<NavigationMessage>(OnNavigationMessage);
}

private void OnNavigationMessage(NavigationMessage navigationMessage)
{
    switch (navigationMessage.NavType)
    {
         case NavType.One:
             var newOne = new One(navigationMessage.Args);
             // use newOne;
             // ...

         // ...
    }
}
```

For UI navigation, you will need to make sure that whatever `Factory` objects you write will also create the `View` as well as the `ViewModel`.

In practice, if you want to write your own navigation service, then you will need to write a navigation service specific to each platform you support - as each platform has different navigation techniques and lifecycles (Android has `Intent`s, WP has `Uri`s, iOS has code-based transitions, etc).

Since MvvmCross already provides a cross-platform navigation service, you may find it easier to use this and to adapt it using a custom presenter - this is discussed in:

- https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation
- https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#custom-presenters

Comment: Sorry for the general comment it does not work. :) What I mean by that is when I publish the message I'am expecting my debugger to fire the constructor of the PurchasesDataEntryViewModel class but it does not do that. I dont know if that makes any sense to you.

Comment: So what happens after I publish the message. How do I move to my target viewmodel. I do not want to use ShowViewModel. This is the main reason I used the plugin in the first place. To avoid ShowViewModel.

Comment: If you do not want to use `ShowViewModel` and the MvvmCross presenter, but instead want some custom code, then you have to write that code - it will have to show activities on Droid, perform Uri page navigations on Windows and create and push viewcontrollers on iOS

Comment: Hi Stuart, My overall goal was to pass data between screens without ha ving to reinstantiate a new viewmodel everytime. I need this because when I travel back and forth the system to maintain the same instance at most times.

Comment: "without ha ving to reinstantiate a new viewmodel" conflicts with you wanting "to fire the constructor of the PurchasesDataEntryViewModel"

Comment: Sorry that was an invalid comment.